# Access tables from SqlProcedure written in an external C# DLL

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Im currently developing a C#-DLL that will be executed from within the SQL Server. I've got a method that looks something like this:

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static SqlString MyProcedure(string param)
{
  // some code here
}
```

Inside this method, I'd like to query some tables and (although its although its another method) insert rows into another table. I can't do this in SQL itselft, since this method will be reading and analyzing PDF files.

I started looking into the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext` for some kind of object, that would represent the database itselft, but didn't find anything that would help me.

I then thought of creating another client using a `new SqlConnection`. But the connection needs some kind of reference to the server and I'm not sure, how to provide this kind of information.
The connection string comes to mind, but for maintainance reasons, I dont want to put the connection string hardcoded into my SQL scripts.

Does anyone know, how to access tables from inside the `MyProcedure` method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Context connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345135(v=sql.90).aspx#mandataac_topic5) is what you want.

```
using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")) {
    c.Open();
    // do something with the connection
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charme :) exactly what i needed